# Windows 10 shared folder can't be accessed from other computer

Tags: windows-10, shared-folders, shared-access

I shared a folder in my personal computer in order to allow my wife to access it from her computer. Followed all instructions related to activate NetBIOS, allow insecure host etc. But when she tries to access the folder, the result is always an error message telling her she can't access. She even can see the shared folder, but can't access it.

I spent the last 29 years using Linux. Before this I was a Unix user. My Windows knowledge is terribly close to nothing.

Some suggestions?

Comment: What is the folder? Perhaps add a screen shot to your question.  Not all Windows folders are easily shared - some are, some are not. That is why a screen shot will help,

Comment: It is a commom folder in an external hard drive. I want to map it in all computers we use to use as backup unit. No special folder, no system folder. Just a plain common folder, @John.